# Вычисление времени MIDI

Tags: c#, время, аудио, naudio, музыка

Я использую библиотеку NAudio для своего проекта на C#. Библиотека помогает прочитать файл MIDI, и выдает его как список событий. У каждого события есть время относительно предыдущего в тиках. Как можно, зная количество тиков на удар, темп (в ударах в минуту), и количество микросекунд в ударе, вычислить время относительно предыдущего события в миллисекундах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если умножим количество тиков на удар*темп (в ударах в минуту), узнаем N=количество тиков в минуте, или 60000 миллисекунд. Значит, на каждый тик приходится 60000/N миллисекунд. Умножим это на время относительно предыдущего в тиках.

Comment: У меня получилось, что количество миллисекунд на тик - 1,25. Но это невозможно, реальная песня играется медленнее.

Comment: Извините, проблема была не в этом. Ваше решение верно.